# Registering impact assessment method for LCA in brightway gives Type Error

Tags: brightway

I'm trying to create new impact assessment methods for performing life-cycle analysis in Brightway. 
I did:

```
bw2data.ia_data_store.ImpactAssessmentDataStore(name=('Air pollutants', 'Ammonia')).register(name=('Air pollutants', 'Ammonia'))
```

But I get :

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.
More precisely, the error occurs when the register(self,**kwargs) function from the file data_store.py is called.

I first thought this was because I did not give any metadata (only a name) but according to the documentation I can't set metadata before registering...

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could correct my code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong place to register a new Method. You should use the `Method` class directly: https://docs.brightwaylca.org/technical/bw2data.html#method From the doc: "A manager for an impact assessment method. This class can register or deregister methods, write intermediate data, process data to parameter arrays, validate, and copy methods."

Answer (score 0):

You should specifically use the `Method` ImpactAssessmentDataStore.

```
new_method_name = ('test', 'this', 'out')
Method(new_method_name).register()
```

The method is now in your DataStore:

```
In    [m for m in methods if m[0]=='test']
Out   [('test', 'this', 'out')]
```

You can then add data (i.e. actually add characterization factors) like this:

```
Method(('test', 'this', 'out')).write(data)
```